# Pass javascript var on blade syntax

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

I have a problem in passing vars into blade syntax with laravel, this is the js code

```
var e = document.getElementById("select-city");
var idCity = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var map = L.map('map').setView([{{ $region->cities->find(idCity)->lat }}, 10.2941], 15);
```

so i want to pass **idCity** js var as a param for **find()** method.

Comment: Is find() method php side?

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök yes exactly

Comment: so you can not use this way. You should to use ajax to get  $region->cities->find( idCity );   result.

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök the problem that i don't have ideas for how to work with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain that doing it using ajax.
Function and variable names just example. you can modify for yourself.

in routes.php  file

```
Route::post('/regionCitiesFind', "yourController@finderOrSomething");
```

in yourController

```
public static function finderOrSomething( Request $request){

  $result $region->cities->find( $request->idCity )->lat; // as your code
  return $result;
}
```

in your view ( blade )  -  for ajax

```
var e = document.getElementById("select-city");
var idCity = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./regionCitiesFind",
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
    data: "_token={{ csrf_token() }}&idCity="+id,
    success: function(msg){

                var map = L.map('map').setView([ msg, 10.2941];

            }
 });
```

I tried explain main structure for using ajax in laravel. There can be syntax errors or missing something for your project.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Erkan's answer, I've always wrapped the blade code in double quotes and assigned to a var, like so:

```
var v = "{{ $region->cities->find(idCity)->lat }}";
```

Then you can do whatever with v, parseFloat, parseInt, etc...